# Cross browser No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: cross-browser

Trying to get add from mobicow.On loading this URL got an xml response .But from my website 
shows this error...

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cdn.mobicow.com/feed/get/pub/4792/sub/{id}/ip/184.72.184.19/ua/Mozil…537.36/ref/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comikka.com%2F/lang/en-US/kw/0/c/2/compliant/0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://localhost:8080'` is therefore not allowed access.**

my code 
                                                                                                                                var url='http://cdn.mobicow.com/feed/get/pub/4792/sub/3352/ip/184.72.184.19/ua/Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F36.0.1985.143%20Safari%2F537.36/ref/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comikka.com%2F/lang/en-US/kw/0/c/2/compliant/0'

```
 $.get(url, function( data ) {
     alert( 'Successful cross-domain AJAX request.' );
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and how? Please provide some context.

Comment: Cross-domain problem -.-" Server origin and client are in the same host. You have to disable web security in your browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711924/disable-cross-domain-web-security-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when you are using AJAX.

If you page is loaded by going to

http://www.domain1.com/samplefirstpage.php

And you ajax wants to load something from

http://www.antherdoomain.com/anotherpage.php

You will get this error

If you keep that in mind, you should be able to hunt down the reason why your code is giving you this error

Cheers