# firefox extension works through sdk but not when installed in browser - compatibility issue?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

---Update----

After experimenting more with this, I've determined that the contentScript I have written is not the problem here. For example, if I reduce the extension to merely:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var self = require("sdk/self");


var button = buttons.ActionButton({
id: "library-link",
label: "External Resource Locator",
icon: self.data.url("icon-16.png"),
  });
```

The button will still appear when I run the extension through the SDK, but will not appear when I install the xpi in a current firefox browser (version 38, on some platforms). This problem seems to be occurring at a very basic level in their design process.

---

I am trying to write a simple extension for firefox which appends a form to the current page and posts data to another site. It can be called by an action button or through a context menu item.

I have been developing with the add-on sdk and it is working perfectly when I use `cfx run` to test it. However, after doing `cfx xpi` and installing the extension into my firefox browser, it does not work at all. The action button and context menu item do not appear, and although the extension shows up under add-ons -> extensions as installed and enabled, none of the images packaged with the xpi will display.

I am not sure what could be causing this, and my code is fairly brief, so I will add my entire main.js:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
                            label: "Look for selected text in the Library of Babel",
                            context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
                             contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                            'var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                            'var formext = document.createElement("form");' +
                            'formext.setAttribute("method", "POST");' +
                            'formext.setAttribute("action", "https://libraryofbabel.info/resourcelocator.cgi");' +
                            'var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");' +
                            ' hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");' +
                             'hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "extension");' +
                            ' hiddenField.setAttribute("value", window.getSelection().toString());' +
                            ' formext.appendChild(hiddenField);' +
                            ' document.body.appendChild(formext);' +
                            ' formext.submit();' +
                            '});',
                            image: self.data.url("icon-16.png")
                            });

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
id: "library-link",
label: "External Resource Locator",

icon: {
"16": "./icon-16.png",
"32": "./icon-32.png",
"64": "./icon-64.png"
},
onClick: function() {
 require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
                              contentScriptFile: data.url("form.js")
                               });
                              }
                              });
```

I've noticed that when I run `cfx xpi` the automatically generated install.rdf file says the maximum version for compatibility is 30.0. However, I have also found that on some computers running versions of firefox up to and including 38 it will work perfectly.  Is there anything in this code which would prevent compatibility with newer versions of firefox? I will add the ContentScriptFile in case that may be responsible:

```
function getSelectedText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
}

var bodytext = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
var formext = document.createElement("form");
formext.setAttribute("method", "POST");
formext.setAttribute("action", "https://libraryofbabel.info/resourcelocator.cgi");
//formext.setAttribute("target","_blank");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "extension");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", getSelectedText() || document.body.innerHTML); // take selected text OR bodytext

formext.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(formext);
formext.submit();
```

Comment: Do you have a github repository of the full addon? I would like to instal the addon myself and see

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at it - you can install the add-on from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lobthis/ - or download the xpi from here: http://libraryofbabel.info/lobthis.xpi

Comment: To update, I've tried it now on a number of different platforms and have had trouble identifying patterns as to what causes it to fail - I've tried two Windows 7 machines where it hasn't worked, but had success with one windows 8 machine. The results have also been mixed with OS X.

Comment: Is main.js and from.js the only place you have your code?

Comment: Yes - the only other thing in the archive are the icons and the files generated by `cfx xpi` like install.rdf.

Comment: It works at Firefox 40. Which versions do not work for you?

Comment: Basileus! I have found that it will work on some machines and not on others, even though they may both be using the same version of firefox. For example, I have successfully installed the extension on a Windows 8 laptop with firefox 38, but have not been able to install it on an OS X machine with the same version of firefox. I haven't been able to test it broadly enough (dont have access to enough computers) to know if the problem is exclusively or at all tied to the operating system.

Comment: Or to know if its tied to version, or some combination of the two, to answer your question more directly.

Comment: By way of update, I tried removing lines of code to see where the problem lies, and got all the way down to just requiring a button and giving it an icon, without any other script in the extension, with the same problems. The button still appears when I run the extension through the sdk, but not when installed in my browser.

Comment: Hey @Notidart and Basilevs - I updated my question after experimenting more with the code. It seems that the problem is not with my contentScript. Let me know if either of you have more ideas as to what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open context menu on the toolbar where your icon would be, select `Customize...`. In the opened window, can you see your icon in "Additional tools and features"? If yes, then it means firefox remembered the icon's absence while you were developing the addon. You can put the icon to the toolbar manually. I believe regular users will not face this problem.
2. Change your `em:maxVersion` manually in `install.rdf`
3. Configure your firefox as described in [Setting up an extension development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment), namely, at least these:

   - `javascript.options.showInConsole = true` to have addon errors shown in F12 console
   - `javascript.options.strict = true` to have even more warnings in the console
   - `extensions.logging.enabled = true` to have installation/update problems in the console.

   After that, restart firefox and see if you can get anything useful from console. Disable other addons to remove the noise.
4. Try to backup and remove the entire [firefox's profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data), to have firefox 100% clean. Does it help? If yes, that narrow the problem to something in profile.
5. Try to change all identifiers of your addon (including addon name, ID, description, button id and description, etc), thus making a new duplicate addon. Does that help? If yes, that most likely means firefox has remembered some settings for your addon while you played with it.

Comment: No, my icon does not appear under Additional tools and features

Comment: UPDATE: more troubleshooting added

Comment: Thank you, @Codeguard - interestingly, when I create a separate Dev profile and launch the browser from the command line as described in the link you provided the extension works. It still does not work from my default profile when the browser is opened normally, however. The only thing resembling an error when I enable the extension is: `TypeError: "Services" is read-only` When I disable, it says `ReferenceError: reference to undefined property cuddlefishSandbox.xulappSandbox bootstrap.js:344:2`

Comment: And `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.nukeSandbox] bootstrap.js:290:0` - I am not sure if these are relevant - I can provide other information from the console if you think it would be helpful

Comment: Please proceed with steps 4 and 5. Since there're no errors on console (and I hope you configured settings correctly), that could be that firefox is hiding your icon due to some settings, and it does not fail to create it.

Comment: By the way, both errors you copied from console indeed refer to your addon, file `bootstrap.js`. I suggest that you compare it against well-working firefox.

Comment: Regarding step 4 - if I remove the profile folder firefox won't start - how can i remove the folder and still get firefox to start?

Comment: The bootstrap.js file I have was auto-generated by the `cfx xpi` command - are there any known errors for auto-generated bootstrap files?

Comment: I don't know whether auto-generated bootstrap.js have any problems. Once again I suggest that you compare bad firefox output vs good firefox output. Removing the profile folder most certainly does not prevent firefox from starting. Instead, it will start clean and ask whether to import settings from other browsers. You must have deleted a wrong folder.

Comment: The folder I removed was the one suggested on the page you linked to - `firefox/profiles/*.default-*` - the message I got when attempting to open firefox was `Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible` - after which the program would not launch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80089/discussion-between-codeguard-and-jonathan-basile).