# Disable cross domain web security in Firefox v.68

Tags: javascript, firefox

In Firefox, how do I do the equivalent of --disable-web-security in Chrome.

I tried to set security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy: false, but no use.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

../font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: I found an add-on which can enable CORS (**https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/**).

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Disable cross domain web security in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711924/disable-cross-domain-web-security-in-firefox)