# Nodejs Json Parsing

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express, jqgrid

I am trying load json data using node js for jqgrid. I am using jqgrid and Express Js also. When I run node js it's not loading the json file. Can anyone help me what could be the issue. Here is the node js code snippet:

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var config = require('./data.json');

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/griddemo.html')
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

Comment: Try `console.log(config);`

Comment: @RobertRozas correct!! Please print the log and check show us the error.

Comment: Is the data.json file i the same path as the file containing the code you provided? Does the data.json file contain a valid json?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with data.json file path or might be problem with  json file. I have tried your script, its working for me. My suggestion is keep an  eye on json file path.

Answer (score 0):

You load your JSON data in the `config` object, then you do nothing with this object.

I suppose you want to pass this config in the HTML file in order to configure the jqgrid plugin (that I don't know BTW).

In this case you should use a templating language to generate a dynamic page (EJS will be more familiar for you if you have previously done PHP, else you should keep - for now - the default one, jade) and pass your config object to the template you made from your HTML.

To illustrate:

```
...
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');//Don't forget to install the ejs module
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/griddemo.ejs', {jqgridConfig: config})
})
...
```

*app.js*

```
...
<script>
  var jqgrid_config = <%- JSON.stringify(jqgridConfig) %>;
</script>
...
```

*griddemo.ejs*

If you don't already know the [express app generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html), you should better use it, it will highly help you to understand the concepts you need in order to render a dynamic page with Express.

Another way to do the job without generate dynamic pages is to put `data.json` in `/public` and to load this JSON file from `griddemo.html` (see [how to use json file in html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070631/how-to-use-json-file-in-html-code))